# How do I install plugins for collectd

Tags: software-installation, plugin, statistics

I have installed collectd and got it running but also wanted to use the Ping plugin ( https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:Ping ) but it's not actually installed by default (i.e. not in the list of plugins in /opt/collectd/lib/collectd

How do I install a plugin that doesn't come with collectd and where do I get the plugin itself?

I have been Googling in circles for this but can't find anything.

Thanks,

Comment: I had installed the liboping required library and tried reinstalling collectd in case this might help, but it didn't. There was a "no" beside it (ping plugin) when installing but no dependency listed beside it and still no ping plugin in the plugin directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out at last. I installed the EPEL Repos and then did the following (for CentOS anyway):

```
# Install collectd-ping plugin. See http://www.rpmfind.net//linux/RPM/fedora/devel/rawhide/x86_64/c/collectd-ping-5.4.1-2.fc21.x86_64.html and above for versions

yum install collectd-ping.x86_64

cp /usr/lib64/collectd/ping.so /opt/collectd/lib/collectd/
```

Now when I run collectd I don't get my old error: "Found a configuration for the `ping' plugin, but the plugin isn't loaded or didn't register a configuration callback."

I get another error "ping plugin: ping_host_add (10.0.1.29) failed: No such device" but from Googling and looking at the Collectd FAQ, this one should be easier to solve!

Comment: Unfortunately the above gave me an old version of the collectd-ping plugin so I had to go with the below compiling of the source.
'
cd /tmp
wget ftp://mirror.switch.ch/pool/4/mirror/fedora/linux/development/rawhide/x86_64/os/Packages/c/collectd-ping-5.4.1-2.fc21.x86_64.rpm
rpm2cpio collectd-ping-5.4.1-2.fc21.x86_64.rpm | cpio -vid
cp /tmp/usr/lib64/collectd/ping.so /opt/collectd/lib/collectd/
'

Answer (score 1):

You can enable any plugin you like in `/etc/collectd/collectd.conf` by uncommenting the plugin line:

```
# /etc/collectd/collectd.conf

#LoadPlugin perl
LoadPlugin ping
#LoadPlugin powerdns
```

and the ping config:

```
<Plugin ping>
       Host "host.foo.bar"
       Host "host.baz.qux"
       TTL 255
</Plugin>
```

If you did not find a plugin, that possibly means there is no plugin.
If you want to write a plugin, just get the collectd sources and read
the doc's. There are a lot of examples on how to write plugins.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately I had already done that at the beginning. It seems the plugin is a part of CollectD but will only be added at install if certain conditions are meet, but since no dependencies are listed beside the plugin name during install. I don't know what is missing or the problem.